# Signing iPhone Configuration XML Profile with Ruby on Rails

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I am generating a valid iPhone Configuration XML Profile and delivering it via a Rails page.

I am trying to figure out how to programmatically sign the XML file with an x509 certificate so that the iPhone recognizes it as a signed profile

This is a good tutorial about what's involved in signing an iPhone Config Profile
http://www.rootmanager.com/iphone-ota-configuration/iphone-ota-setup-with-signed-mobileconfig.html

Specifically, doing this on the command line would sign the unsigned file `company.mobileconfig`

`openssl smime -sign -in company.mobileconfig -out signed.mobileconfig -signer server.crt -inkey server.key -certfile cert-chain.crt -outform der -nodetach`

What would the equivalent command be in Ruby on Rails, assuming I have the XML file in a string?  I can find alot of documentation about serving content over a SSL connection with rails, but not alot about signing arbitrary content before delivery.

Comment: Any chance you can share some of the rails code you wrote for serving this? (github maybe) . Im trying to set this up as well, but the apple documentation has me lost and not too many details in the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below lines of code will sign the iPhone configuration XML Profile.

```
ssl_key_str = File.read("/path/to/private.key”)
ssl_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ssl_key_str)

ssl_cert_str = File.read("/path/to/certificate.crt”) 
ssl_cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(ssl_cert_str)

profile = File.read("/path/to/profile.mobileconfig")

signed_profile = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(ssl_cert, ssl_key, profile, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
```

Comment: what happend to the "-certfile cert-chain.crt" parameter of the openssl command line tool?

how do i add this to the OpenSSL Module of ruby? i can not find any solutions

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI — I had to add `to_der` to the end to get mine to work:

```
sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(cert, key, profile, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_der
```