# how to encrypt and sign iphone mobile configuration file using Ruby

Tags: iphone, ruby, encryption, configuration, openssl

I have a unsigned mobileconfig file in xml format (template) generated by iphone configuration utility. I would like to encrypt and sign it using openssl and be able to install it on iphone using Ruby on rails. I do not want to create a SCEP server to do this as I want to keep modifying this template xml file dynamically and serve it using some URL.

Thanks for your help in advance.

I have already checked following question but it is not clear from it how to encrypt the file that can be installed correctly on iphone - as I keep getting "config file could not be installed due to unknown error" when I tried to mimic encrypted file format from iphone configuration utility by only encrypting the  part and appending/prepending other parts of the configuration file appropriately.

[Signing iPhone Configuration XML Profile with Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446247/signing-iphone-configuration-xml-profile-with-ruby-on-rails)

This manual by apple is useful but its more geared for creating a SCEP server and not for manipulating template mobileconfig file -

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/profile-service/profile-service.html

Comment: are you talking about something related to Jailbreak?

Comment: No - I want it to be done for non jailbroken iphone.

Comment: I hear you! I'm struggling with exactly the same thing at the moment—signing profiles works perfectly, but encrypting a profile only garners the error "Decryption key for this profile is not installed." I'll add an answer here if I find one.

One tip I can give though: if you install the iPhone Configuration Utility and connect your device via USB cable, you can see additional error messages (such as the one above) in the console tab. It might help a little.

Comment: An email reminded me I promised to update here if I solved this. I did, but not in Ruby. See bash script at https://github.com/Calrion/Melange/tree/master/profilesign (requires PlistBuddy, so OS X only, sorry).

Answer (score 2):

Incase if still anybody is having issues with signing and encrypting the profile with Ruby, following answer would be useful.

I have used [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module available in Ruby and [Plist](https://rubygems.org/gems/plist/versions/3.1.0) gem.

Consider a passcode restriction profile.

```
passcode_payload ={
              'PayloadUUID' => 'RANDOM_STRING_UUID',
              'PayloadOrganization' => 'PayloadOrganization',
              'PayloadVersion' => 1,
              'PayloadIdentifier' => 'com.test.PayloadIdentifier',
              'PayloadType' => 'Configuration',
              'PayloadDisplayName' => 'PayloadDisplayName',
              'PayloadRemovalDisallowed' => false
            }
  passcode_payload_content = {
              'PayloadDescription' => 'PayloadDescription',
              'PayloadDisplayName' => 'PayloadDisplayName',
              'PayloadIdentifier' => 'PayloadIdentifier',
              'PayloadOrganization' => 'PayloadOrganization',
              'PayloadType' => 'com.apple.mobiledevice.passwordpolicy',
              'PayloadUUID' => "RANDOM_STRING_UUID",
              'PayloadVersion' => 1,
              'allowSimple' => true,
              'forcePIN' => true
              'maxPINAgeInDays' => 20,
              'minComplexChars' => 1,
              'minLength' => 4,
              'requireAlphanumeric' => true
            }
```

**

### Encryption

**

Usually for a normal profile the `passcode_payload_content` goes into the `passcode_payload['PayloadContent']` as array of dictionaries.

<strike>passcode_payload['PayloadContent'] = [passcode_payload_content]</strike>

But for an encrypted profile, `PayloadContent` should be removed and  `EncryptedPayloadContent` should be used as per the [configuration profile key reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW52).

from the doc,

> To encrypt a profile do the following:
>
> Remove the `PayloadContent` array and serialize it as a proper plist.
>
> Note that the top-level object in this plist is an array, not a
>   dictionary.
>
> CMS-encrypt the serialized plist as enveloped data.
>   Serialize the encrypted data in DER format.
>
> Set the serialized data as
>   the value of as a Data plist item in the profile, using the key
>   `EncryptedPayloadContent`

Since top level object in the plist should be an array

```
passcode_payload_content_array = [passcode_payload_content]
```

Serializing to proper plist

```
to_be_encrypted_plist = passcode_payload_content_array.to_plist
```

Encrypting the certificate payload content,

```
device_certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read('deviceIdentityCertificate.pem')
encrypted_payload = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([device_certificate],to_be_encrypted_plist, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc"),OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
```

Add encrypted payload content to the original payload in der format

```
passcode_payload['EncryptedPayloadContent'] = StringIO.new(encrypted_payload.to_der)
```

**

### Signing

**

```
signed_passcode_profile = OpenSSL::PKCS7.sign(SSL_CERTIFICATE, SSL_KEY, passcode_payload.to_plist, [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
```

At last, you can use

```
send_data signed_passcode_profile.to_der, :type => "application/x-apple-aspen-config"
```

to send the payload.

Answer (score -1):

> The link you mentioned talks only about signing the iPhone configuration profile. Does atleast signing a profile works for you?
>   You can verify that signature generated by your code is correct using openssl command line utility. Write the generated signature to a file and use following command to verify signature and extract original data from pkcs#7 signature.
>
> > openssl smime -verify -inform DER -in signed_config.p7s -signer your_signing_certificate -out data.txt