# How to encrypt the mobile configuration profiles in iOS (in OTA deployments)?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoa

I am trying to sign and encrypt `.mobileconfig` profiles for iOS devices.

Signing works perfectly using `openssl::pkcs7` sign function in ruby,

however using encrypt function, I get an encrypted data but Safari fails to install the profile saying **"Invalid Profile"**.

There are two questions in this regard:

1. Which data from the .mobileconfig profile is actually encrypted that
   goes into the  (data)..(/data) section of the (key)
   EncryptedPayloadContent (/key) ?
2. Is the data in binary format (`.der`) or base64 encoded?

Any help in this regard would be helpful as APPLE severely lacks any documentation in encrypting the profiles.

Comment: I'm not sure you'd ever be able to do this, since you can't instruct safari to decrypt your profiles before attempting to import it into the system keychain. Since you mention safari, I assume you're attempting to install the profiles via that. Perhaps you can store them encrypted on the server, decrypt on request (enter a key in a html form, etc) and send the decrypted version over SSL to the device?

Answer (score 0):

This question is same as an [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087415/how-to-encrypt-and-sign-iphone-mobile-configuration-file-using-ruby?lq=1). Reposting the answer here, with some modifications!

I have used [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html) module available in Ruby and [Plist](https://rubygems.org/gems/plist/versions/3.1.0) gem.

Consider a passcode restriction profile.

```
passcode_payload ={
              'PayloadUUID' => 'RANDOM_STRING_UUID',
              'PayloadOrganization' => 'PayloadOrganization',
              'PayloadVersion' => 1,
              'PayloadIdentifier' => 'com.test.PayloadIdentifier',
              'PayloadType' => 'Configuration',
              'PayloadDisplayName' => 'PayloadDisplayName',
              'PayloadRemovalDisallowed' => false
            }
  passcode_payload_content = {
              'PayloadDescription' => 'PayloadDescription',
              'PayloadDisplayName' => 'PayloadDisplayName',
              'PayloadIdentifier' => 'PayloadIdentifier',
              'PayloadOrganization' => 'PayloadOrganization',
              'PayloadType' => 'com.apple.mobiledevice.passwordpolicy',
              'PayloadUUID' => "RANDOM_STRING_UUID",
              'PayloadVersion' => 1,
              'allowSimple' => true,
              'forcePIN' => true
              'maxPINAgeInDays' => 20,
              'minComplexChars' => 1,
              'minLength' => 4,
              'requireAlphanumeric' => true
            }
```

Usually for a normal profile the `passcode_payload_content` goes into the `passcode_payload['PayloadContent']` as array of dictionaries.

<strike>passcode_payload['PayloadContent'] = [passcode_payload_content]</strike>

But for an encrypted profile, `PayloadContent` should be removed and  `EncryptedPayloadContent` should be used as per the [configuration profile key reference document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW52).

**Question 1:** *Which data from the .mobileconfig profile is actually encrypted that goes into the (data)..(/data) section of the (key) EncryptedPayloadContent (/key)*

from the doc,

> To encrypt a profile do the following:
>
> Remove the `PayloadContent` array and serialize it as a proper plist.
>
> Note that the top-level object in this plist is an array, not a
>   dictionary.
>
> CMS-encrypt the serialized plist as enveloped data.
>   Serialize the encrypted data in DER format.
>
> Set the serialized data as
>   the value of as a Data plist item in the profile, using the key
>   `EncryptedPayloadContent`

Since top level object in the plist should be an array

```
passcode_payload_content_array = [passcode_payload_content]
```

Serializing to proper plist

```
to_be_encrypted_plist = passcode_payload_content_array.to_plist
```

Encrypting the certificate payload content,

```
device_certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read('deviceIdentityCertificate.pem')
encrypted_payload = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([device_certificate],to_be_encrypted_plist, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("des-ede3-cbc"),OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
```

**Question 2:** *Is the data in binary format (.der) or base64 encoded?*

Add encrypted payload content to the original payload in der format

```
passcode_payload['EncryptedPayloadContent'] = StringIO.new(encrypted_payload.to_der)
```