# Apple MDM - Profile could not be decrypted (Decryption key for this profile is not installed)

Tags: ios, ruby, encryption, openssl, mdm

I am implementing Apple MDM Profile Service in C++ using the Apple OTA Profile Delivery example (which is in Ruby). It seems all things work well except the last step (configuration applying).

IPhone Configuration Utility shows the following:

> Jul  8 16:38:48 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
>
> Jul  8 16:38:48 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: Checking for MDM installation...
>
> Jul  8 16:38:48 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: ...finished checking for MDM installation.
>
> Jul  8 16:38:50 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: Enrolling in OTA Profile service...
>
> Jul  8 16:38:51 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: Attempting to retrieve issued certificate...
>
> Jul  8 16:38:51 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: Issued certificate received.
>
> Jul  8 16:38:52 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Note ) MC: Retrieving profile from OTA Profile service...
>
> Jul  8 16:38:52 iPhone profiled[1454] : (Error) MC: Decryption failed:  NSError:
>
> Desc   : Profile could not be decrypted
>
> Sugg   : Decryption key for this profile is not installed.
>
> US Desc: Profile could not be decrypted
>
> US Sugg: Decryption key for this profile is not installed.
>
> Domain : MCProfileErrorDomain
>
> Code   : 1006
>
> Type   : MCFatalError

It seems like it is a common error, because I found a couple of discussions on discussions.apple.com, but they do not have solutions. Also I have found [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7087415/how-to-encrypt-and-sign-iphone-mobile-configuration-file-using-ruby#comment13105686_7087415) here, but it is without a solution too.

The Apple Ruby example which is in [Over-the-Air Profile Delivery Concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/networkinginternet/conceptual/iphoneotaconfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html) works well. I have compared outputs (certificate dumps) of my C++ implementation and the Ruby example. They are the same except domain names (I use "TEST" instead of "ACME". I tried to use the original certificates, but they did not work in my implementation either.).

I use the same encryption in the code to send a new certificate to the device side. It works.

In the case of profile encryption I use certificates from the PKCS7 which is received from the device side. So I do not think that the problem is because of an incorrect use of OpenSSL.

Can you suggest me anything?

**UPDATE1:**

1) Actually when I say that certificates (mine and from the example) are the same I mean that they have the same dependencies and I mean that it seems like my and the example algorithms work similarly. Surely the certificates have different fingerprints, etc.

2) **I use the exact algorithm as in the Ruby example from the Over-the-Air Profile Delivery Concepts link.** So as far as I understand I use SCEP.

Here is my C++ code (I mainly removed code for logging). Yes, I understand that my code is rough, but on this stage I need only a working algorithm.

**C-x509-request-from-device.pem**

```
PKCS #10 Certificate Request (Version 1.0)
Subject: CN=Profile Service (4feea0ef-b586-4c54-a767-5d8160a04952), O=TEST Inc.
Public Key: X.509 format RSA key

Extension Request:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
   DigitalSignature
   Key_Encipherment
]
```

**E-pkcs7-degenerated.pem**

```
Owner: CN=Profile Service (4feea0ef-b586-4c54-a767-5d8160a04952), O=TEST Inc.
Issuer: CN=TEST Root CA (314aa3fe-ea1f-4afb-b2f5-ad998f1eddf3), O=None
Serial number: 145
Valid from: Wed Jul 09 22:38:04 NOVT 2014 until: Thu Jul 10 22:38:04 NOVT 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  B4:F4:78:E3:A1:69:FB:23:49:E8:0D:4C:E5:8F:C5:A6
     SHA1: 47:19:8A:9C:9F:91:B2:FC:6B:ED:EE:A8:41:FF:3B:CF:6A:1D:52:F2
     SHA256: 59:95:31:66:B8:D8:54:83:B5:23:17:86:1A:7F:94:98:B2:17:58:61:F8:
      0A:4C:E8:B0:1C:4D:79:23:B0:32:93
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

 Extensions:

 #1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
 KeyUsage [
   DigitalSignature
   Key_Encipherment
 ]
```

**/profile** (the second POST; my response on it causes the "Profile could not be decrypted" error)

```
PKCS7Wrap pkcs7;
pkcs7.InitFromDER(httpData.block_, httpData.blockSize_);

std::string content;

// ...........

SavePKCS7ToFile(pkcs7.pkcs7_, "K-pkcs7-from-device-2.pem");

std::string tmp = appleMDMPList_.GetClientCertConfPayloadPList("foo");

SaveData(tmp, "3-client-cert-conf.xml");

PKCS7Wrap encryptedContent;
PKCS7Wrap::EncryptData(pkcs7.GetCertificates(), tmp, encryptedContent);

if (encryptedContent.IsInited())
{
    SavePKCS7ToFile(encryptedContent.pkcs7_, "Q-encrypted_profile.pem");

    content =
        appleMDMPList_.GetConfigurationPayloadPList(encryptedContent.ToDER());

    SaveData(content, "4-configuration.xml");
}

std::string signedProfile;
PKCS7Wrap::SignData(keyStore.GetAppleMDMSSLCrt(),
    keyStore.GetAppleMDMSSLKey(), content, signedProfile);  

// send to the device with mime = application/x-apple-aspen-config
```

**K-pkcs7-from-device-2.pem**

```
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Profile Service (4feea0ef-b586-4c54-a767-5d8160a04952), O=TEST Inc.
Issuer: CN=TEST Root CA (314aa3fe-ea1f-4afb-b2f5-ad998f1eddf3), O=None
Serial number: 145
Valid from: Wed Jul 09 22:38:04 NOVT 2014 until: Thu Jul 10 22:38:04 NOVT 2014
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  B4:F4:78:E3:A1:69:FB:23:49:E8:0D:4C:E5:8F:C5:A6
     SHA1: 47:19:8A:9C:9F:91:B2:FC:6B:ED:EE:A8:41:FF:3B:CF:6A:1D:52:F2
     SHA256: 59:95:31:66:B8:D8:54:83:B5:23:17:86:1A:7F:94:98:B2:17:58:61:F8:
0A:4C:E8:B0:1C:4D:79:23:B0:32:93
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
   DigitalSignature
   Key_Encipherment
]


Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=TEST Root CA (314aa3fe-ea1f-4afb-b2f5-ad998f1eddf3), O=None
Issuer: CN=TEST Root CA (314aa3fe-ea1f-4afb-b2f5-ad998f1eddf3), O=None
Serial number: 1
Valid from: Mon Jul 07 19:28:55 NOVT 2014 until: Tue Jul 07 19:28:55 NOVT 2015
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  78:20:18:80:9C:09:D9:DA:36:3E:06:CC:F7:61:A9:13
     SHA1: 40:61:EA:90:D8:58:20:3C:43:CB:2B:E1:3F:49:DF:A8:5A:7A:01:39
     SHA256: AB:F6:5C:A7:23:F1:92:38:12:71:29:2A:C0:F1:04:69:CF:F4:7C:26:FC:
E7:0C:89:B4:10:A4:E5:58:9F:50:39
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
   CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
 KeyUsage [
    DigitalSignature
   Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
```

]

**UPDATE2:**

I have just regenerated certificates (CA, RA, SSL) and it works. I do no know why :)

Comment: You should provide some code or risk closing for "why is this code not working" without providing any code.

Answer (score 1):

@jww is right. It's impossible to troubleshoot such problem without any code.

My guess is that you are encrypting a profile with the wrong certificate.

> I have compared outputs (certificate dumps) of my C++ implementation and the Ruby example. >They are the same except domain names (I use "TEST" instead of "ACME".

Frankly. This sentense raised red flags in my mind. There should be more than domain name difference. There should be public key difference, serial number adifference and so on.

Most likely, what happens is that you send one certificate to a device and use another to encrypt profile.

BTW. Do you use PKCS12 or SCEP to provide an identity to your device?

Comment: Victor, thank you for your answer. I have updated my issue. Please, see it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I ran into the same thing yesterday and it wound up being a problem with the formatting of the payload that was encrypted, i.e., the "Decryption key for this profile is not installed" error message is a red herring.

The payload that is encrypted has an "array" of "dict", which is different than unencrypted payloads.  This is evident in the test Ruby script Apple provides.  In the sample Ruby script, the PKCS7.encrypt call encrypts the output from client_cert_configuration_payload.  That function emits an array of payloads, as follows: Plist::Emit.dump([webclip_payload, client_cert_payload]). The content that is signed in the /enroll handler is just a "dict", Plist::Emit.dump(payload).

It was very surprising to fix a key not installed problem by changing the contents that the error indicates cannot be decrypted.